# Convince GitHub that plain ASCII PostScript files are diffable

Tags: git, github, diff, postscript

I have a program that is written in PostScript. While GitHub allows me to [view PostScript files as text](https://github.com/notengrafik/fdf2xfdf/blob/8cbdef5f8373bb3a7c78dc7fa9aeb2a60f2ae14d/fdf2xfdf.ps), it says "Binary file not shown" when [comparing commits](https://github.com/notengrafik/fdf2xfdf/compare/8cbdef5f8373bb3a7c78dc7fa9aeb2a60f2ae14d...d35d949d6eaa0ae6987e8814107c2d1053e3ab41).  Adding `.ps diff` in the `.gitattributes` file doesn't make a difference.

All the desktop tools like `git gui` or `meld` have no problem diffing the PostScript code. The code is plain ASCII:

```
$ file -bi fdf2xfdf.ps 
text/plain; charset=us-ascii
```

Comment: This seems like something that would be better directed towards GitHub's support staff.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub describes how it detects file types and decides how to handle them at https://github.com/github/linguist/ . The way it handles PostScript language files is described at [`language.yml#L3504-L3515`](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/lib/linguist/languages.yml#L3504-L3515):

```
PostScript:
  type: markup
  color: "#da291c"
  extensions:
  - ".ps"
  - ".eps"
  - ".pfa"
  tm_scope: source.postscript
  aliases:
  - postscr
  ace_mode: text
  language_id: 291
```

The `type: markup` is perhaps what is preventing you from getting the handling you want. Programming languages have `type: programming`.

Github [respects `.gitattributes`](https://github.com/github/linguist/#using-gitattributes) as a way of controlling how its language processing happens. You might need to set the file path as non-documentation, and as detectable as programming code.

```
$ cat .gitattributes
*.ps linguist-documentation=false
*.ps linguist-detectable=true
```

I have not tested this myself, because I don't want to take the time now to set up a GitHub repository with a PostScript language file in it, then clean it up.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. Alas, [it does not seem to work](https://github.com/th-we/psdifftest/commit/0d77af70e1c1f2bcecc9ee038906df425a3140be)!